# Is there a way to plot ggpredict results in table?

Tags: r, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I used the ggeffects package to calculate the marginal effects of two logistic models (one binary and another multinomial). I was wondering if there is a way to visualize or export this results in a table, similar to the tables presenting the coefficients of the variables in the models as is done by sjPlot and Stargazer.

Comment: Functions from ggeffects return a data frame, so you can use any package that produces a table from data frames. Note that since the latest update, the print method also produces nicer tables, see https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/

Comment: Short note: for instance, `sjPlot::tab_df()` can do this, but I think there are also many other packages.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel. BTW, your work is helping me a lot. I wanted to ask another question if that's ok, now that I'm learning better what ggeffects does. I wanted to know if it's possible to report only the changes in probabilities in a table. ggeffects return the results of probabilities of every response, I'm correct? But I wanted to view or print something like the odds ratio (basically use change in probabilities as the effects, and not the odds ration in a logistic regression model. Anyway, thanks a lot in advance for the help!